How can I get the number of data in an association? [Sequelize],[PostgreSQL]
I need to get the number of unread messages from a fetchAll query. I only need the number.  ----> this is what I am expecting along with the other data ->:"Unread_messages": 55,I do not want other attributes(of message) to be present there.This is a mock code and I have commented where I need the number:
static async fetchData(page: number, DataId: number) {

    const limit = 20;

    const offset = (page - 1) * limit;



    return await Data.findAndCountAll({

      include: [

        { model: SomeData1, as: 'someData1', required: false },

        {

          model: Data2,

          as: 'data2',

          attributes: ['id', 'name'],

          required: true,

          where: { is_deleted: false },

          include: [

            {

              model: Message,     //----> I need the count of this

              as: 'unreadMessageCount',

              where: {

               someDataid: DataId,

                status: 'UNREAD'

              },

              required: false

            }

          ]

        }

      ],

      where: { DataId: DataId },

      offset,

      limit,

      distinct: true

    });

  }

}


try adding it via attributes
{
                  model: Message,     //----> I need the count of this
                  as: 'unreadMessageCount',
                  where: {
                    someDataid: DataId,
                    status: 'UNREAD'
                  },
                  attributes: [
                    [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("id")), "unreadMessageCount"],
                  ],
                  required: false
                }


I already tried that but I got this error -> error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "Message"
